# Uncaught ReferenceError in External JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure why I am getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined.  Can anybody please help me figure this out?

Here is my code for html first. I can't see where the problem is.  I am not sure what the browsers (Edge and Chrome) are talking about.
`<canvas id="test">`
`Your browser does not support the canvas tag.`
`</canvas>`

`<script>testCanvas(); </script>`

Here is my code from my external JS file:

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',test, false);`
`function testCanvas()`
`{`
`var canvas = document.getElementById("test");`
`var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");`
`ctx.fillStyle = "#FBBE00";`
`ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);`
`}`

I have searched high and low by do a lot of research on the internet and consulting my JS books but can't seem to figure out the problem.  I even looked for similar problems here on Stack Overflow but they just refer to JQuery.  I really need some guidance on this problem.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',testCanvas, false);


target.addEventListener(type, callback, options); is the syntax. Test is not a function so it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you don't need to call testCanvas(); in <script>-tags?

Comment: @rehnoj Thank you again for your advice.  I removed the script tags from my html and changed test to testCanvas and it's working.  Many Thanks.

Comment: @JarneKompier I tried the target.addEventListener(type, callback, options); but it doesn't work because the browser says that target is undefined.

Comment: @WilliamBoswall In your case, target is either `document` or `window`

Comment: @JarneKompier I put in the document.addEventListener one and it worked.  The target one just didn't work.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @rehnoj oh okay thank you for the clarification.  Much appreciated.

Comment: With target i meant the dom object you want to add the event listener to. So document works but something like document.getElementById("elid") would also work as a target

Comment: @JarneKompier Thank you I took your change and implemented it and its working really good.  Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has commented.  The solution is now working perfectly.  Thanks again!